# "Sticky" select in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an annoying issue with an app that has an Angular-based frontend. A certain select box is "sticky" - you have to select an option twice to change to it. Here's a snippet which reproduces the issue:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

  app.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Set news data
    $scope.news = {
      specific_for_dealership: '003'
    };

    // Get dealers
    $scope.dealers = [{
      id: 1,
      dealerid: '001',
      name: 'Volvo'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      dealerid: '002',
      name: 'Saab'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      dealerid: '003',
      name: 'Seat'
    }];
  });
</script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="NewsCtrl">
    <form>
      <select name="specific_for_dealership" ng-model="news.specific_for_dealership">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dealer in dealers" ng-selected="news.specific_for_dealership" value="{{ dealer.dealerid }}">{{ dealer.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what has gone wrong and how I might resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to use `ng-selected` to select your option,  `ng-model` does that for you.

It is causing the model to get confused.  Which is why you have to select it twice.

```
 <select name="specific_for_dealership" ng-model="news.specific_for_dealership">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="dealer in dealers"  value="{{ dealer.dealerid }}">{{ dealer.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

Something else I would personally recommend as well is switching to ng-options to display your options list from the object.  It will give you some more versatility.  For example you can bind the whole object to the selector instead of just the ID.

```
<select name="specific_for_dealership" 
     ng-options="dealer.dealerid as dealer.name for dealer in dealers" 
     ng-model="news.specific_for_dealership">
        <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @MatthewDaly Take a look at the second part about `ng-options` that works better and will select the value you are setting the model to better.

Comment: Yes, that works fine so I've applied those changes too

Answer (score 2):

Just set `ng-selected="dealer.dealerid === news.specific_for_dealership"`